# Form Border Style is not properly displayed

Tags: bunifu

This is one problem I can't understand. I'm using windows 10 and by default the form border should be displayed like this:

[image]

But for some reason or the other, my windows form app's form border is like this:

[image]

... despite the form border property is set to `FixedSingle`. I also tried the same with form border property `Fixed3D` but still it is of no use.

It would be great if someone could guide me about how this can be **fixed** and the reason my form's border is wired. **Please download the images to get a clarity of what I'm asking.**

*NOTE*

*Fixed here means to get back the default form border.*

*I also use Bunifu Framework. However I don't know the relevance it has here*

*The image attached was taken during debugging*

Comment: Wow... I’ve never seen that happen on Windows 10. Are your graphics drivers alright?

Comment: _"I also use Bunifu Framework. However I don't know the relevance it has here"_ - I'd say pretty significant

Comment: _"I'm using windows 10 and by default the form border should be displayed like"_ - well your first screenshot is of _Windows Explorer_ which most likely isn't using WinForms on **Windows 10**

Comment: It looks like whatever "bunifu" is may be trying to set a custom border on that window using something like `CreateRoundRectRgn`, but it's not finishing the job by painting the defined non-client area. I would look at whatever code supplies the bitmap/drawing for the non-client area.

Comment: @Dai  Thanks for your concern.... My drivers are all up to date. I'm surprised too :(

Comment: @MickyD Yes But if run a winforms app on windows 10 the border will be like that similar to the explorer window. My previous builds are fine but this is the first project I'm facing a issue like this.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for that suggestion. However it would be more helpful if you could post it as an elaborated answer so that I can actually get it done. Thanks

Comment: Got it. Its the Bunifu Elipse from Bunifu Framework that I was using to get the rounded edges turned out to be the spoiler of my beautiful form. After deleting it I was able to rectify that issue. Sincere thanks to everyone :)